# Does Apache Zeppelin have intellisense?

Tags: intellisense, apache-zeppelin

Does Apache Zeppelin have intellisense/auto-completion support in its notebook ui?

if so how do I use it?

I tried searching on the internet but was unsuccessful to find a source which works. This https://github.com/NFLabs/zeppelin/issues/248 says to use `ctrl-`, but it did not work. I wonder whether intellisense support was removed after the project was moved to Apache.

Comment: Here's a list to the open JIRA issue mentioned: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3259?jql=text%20~%20%22intellisense%22

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After going through the Jira of Apache Zeppelin I found that they have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> as the auto-completion shortcut key. And it works.

Comment: Yes, `Ctrl+.` is the way to do it. But you are right, it should be in the docs and by the way, that is a great way to start contributing to the project :)

Comment: That is press the Ctrl and the dot (.) at the same time.

Comment: it works for me as well, but I think it does not support intelliscence (context completion) @marios

Comment: @HarounMohammedi I get the same as you.  it does something (seems to show local variables and key words) but not what I want it to.  it doesn't auto-complete a variable's methods and attributes which is what we really want.  has anyone got this working

Comment: this is what I get, hope this will be added in the next versions @ninjasmith

Comment: For 0.7.3, it works in spark interpreter, but not in python.
Is there any plan to add autocompletion for python?

Comment: @Chad You get true intellisense in 0.7.3 with a Spark interpreter? I just tried it and I don't. Ctrl+. just lists local variables and keywords.

Comment: @HarounMohammedi Do you know if Zeppelin has plans to support true intellisense?

Comment: I don't know bro, hope they do it very soon @IceMan

Comment: I haven’t opened a JIRA for it. Let’s see how the Devs respond

Comment: Any news in 2020?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the screen shot of all key board shortcuts(Apache Zeppelin Version 0.8.2) including auto completion.

[image]

for auto completion of show is like below screen shot

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the `Ctrl`+`.` shortcut provides some basic auto completion, its not true intellisense as you would be familiar with in for example Visual Studio Code. IMO without intellisense Zeppelin is missing a critical feature for efficient programming.

There are several Jira issues open on it from 2018 but as of today none have been actioned:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3379?jql=project%20%3D%20ZEPPELIN%20AND%20component%20%3D%20interpreter-auto-completion

I'll also add that in my use case, I am trying to connect my notebooks to an existing Apache Spark cluster so I decided to try Jupyter instead hoping for better code completion. The challenge I ran into on that front is that I could not get any Jupyter kernels to connect to my existing spark cluster. Most of the kernels are out of date, the documentation is wrong and/or they only work with particular scala or spark versions. So even if Jupyter has intellisense, I found the lack of easy spark support a roadblock. Maybe Databricks got it right?